# How to hide and show a text by hidden field in JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I want to hide and show a text Cod Shipping charge

```
 `<div class="row">
                    <div class="cell" id="well">Cod Shipping charge</div>
                    <div class="cell free"><?php echo $priceCurrency->getCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();?> <span class="text-shipping-charge"><?php echo number_format($shippingrate,2,'.',''); ?></span></div>
                </div>`
```

when clicking on the payment below code

```
<div class="payment-option">
                        <div class="head" >Part Payment (COD + Online)</div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="cod-block">
                                <div class="cash-option">
                                    <div class="pay-option">
                                        <div class="option-info">20% Online (Now)</div>
                                        <div class="option-cash">â‚¹ 12,650</div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="pay-option">
                                        <div class="option-info">80% Cash On Delivery</div>
                                        <div class="option-cash">â‚¹ 50,000</div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Please Help

Comment: no need to add php tag for this question

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+toggle+div+click+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You mention JQuery so using that it could be something like:

```
$('.payment-option').click(function(){
    $('.row').show();
});
```

Though class .`row` doesn't sound very unique so you may want to assign that element a unique id like

```
<div id="cod_shipping_charge" class="row">
```

then you can use:

```
$('#cod_shipping_charge').show();
```

Comment: Poor question with millions of dupes

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnNewGroup").click(function() {
    $("#newGroup").toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <button id="btnNewGroup">New Group</button>
  <div id="newGroup" style="display:none">Div Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is always nice to write some explanation. It is also useful for the asker when you use their HTML